# Configuring for automatic boot over Avahi kernel requires an x86-64 but i686 detected

Tags: maas

I want to add a node like [here](https://wiki.edubuntu.org/ServerTeam/MAAS/AvahiBoot) but when I mount Pendrive I received an error like this:

```
this kernel requires an x86-64 cpu but only detected an i686 cpu
```

I have some old HP Compaq's with Pentium 4 HT and I can't add this computer.

Answer (score 2):

There's currently no USB image for i386 but it is in progress of being created. Another option for you would be to create a USB Disk of the Ubuntu Server ISO and select:

"Multiple Server Install with MAAS"

Then proceed until you find yourself with

"Install or Enlist with Ubuntu MAAS Server"

And select one from the list or input one.